# Converting Midi files to Audio with NAudio

Tags: .net, midi, naudio

I have recently downloaded and started learning the NAudio library for .NET.
My main goal basically is to convert many midi files to audio (wav/mp3) using soundfonts that I have, after doing some manipulation on the files (for instance - saving each channel to a different audio file).

I could use apps like [synthfont](http://www.synthfont.com/) but the problem is that I want to be able to make massive conversions of many files + make it an automated process, and with those apps it wouldn't be very convenient if not impossible.

So far I have found very little info on how to work with midi/soundfonts with NAudio and I'd be happy if someone could give me an advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio does have some code that can parse SoundFonts and MIDI files, but it does not contain a software synthesizer. You could make one yourself, (pitch shifters and filters are generally enough to play most soundfonts), but it would be quite a lot of work. It would be much easier to find a DAW that you can script. Maybe try REAPER's [ReaScript API](http://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascript.php)?